# Any open source application applying design patterns for multithreading?

Tags: multithreading, design-patterns

I have a multithreading MFC application. But I don't want to have hacky code for threading as it will cause headaches to maintain the system. So I am looking for right patterns for the threading code.

I have read [Pattern-Oriented Software Architecture: Patterns for Concurrent and Networked Objects (POSA2)](http://www.cs.wustl.edu/~schmidt/POSA/POSA2/) but after that reading, I can't help but feel lost somewhere. I think I'd better look at real application applying these design patterns. It does not have to be MFC application or windows application since I want to look at usage of the patterns. Can you give any hint or advice on this?

Comment: If you want to avoid writing "hacky code", the best design pattern, where possible, is to use well-tested, well-maintained, well-documented libraries to do the hard work for you. I don't have an answer to your question, though.

Comment: @Gravity I am not sure that's true. For example, C# programmer can still create a mess with .NET frameworks which is, I think, well-tested, well-maintained,...

Comment: I wasn't trying to suggest that using libraries is guaranteed to result in bug-free code. I'm saying that well-maintained libraries are often less buggy than if you make the same thing yourself. Threading is difficult, so if you can use a well-tested convenience class like a thread pool instead of making it yourself, that should reduce bugs.

Comment: Thanks for clarification. I think my question has the same context as your comment.

Comment: Any particular language?

Comment: @Tudor Currently I am using C++ and MFC for UI.

Comment: @Paul: How complex are the patterns? For simple loops or parallel tasks you can try to use OpenMP or Intel TBB. These are multithreading libraries for C++.

Comment: @Tudor That's exactly [what I asked in the other question.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8557576/does-openmp-work-in-a-mfc-application) :-) But I think I am looking for little more complex cases than that such as communication between threads and optimization of shared resources. Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[I was very close to it and found several ones from the author's web site!](http://www.cs.wustl.edu/~schmidt/TAO.html).